# Pandas throwing ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 219

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`. I want to group by `id`, `type` and `scenario`. Then calculate rolling mean of `val` column and use the result to calculate another version of it as shown below:

```
period = 120
period_2 = 12
group = df.groupby(['id', 'type', 'scenario'], as_index=False)
df['val_rolmean'] = (group['val'].rolling(period_2*2, center=True, min_periods=1).mean() * 12).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df['val_rolmean2'] = (group['val_rolmean']/(group['rate'].shift(period).fillna(0) + 0.0050)).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

but it is throwing this error:

> ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 219

I am using pandas version `1.0.5`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matches more or less what you're looking for.

Since your `df` could contain repeated values for the grouped columns `['id', 'type', 'scenario']`, I created a dataframe `df_grouped` with unique values.

And added each new calculated column to it.

I removed the argument `level=0`, because it wasn't required in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,4,size=(1000, 5)), 
    columns=['id', 'type', 'scenario', 'val', 'rate'])

period = 120
period_2 = 12

# Data Frame with unique lst_col_group values
lst_col_group = ['id', 'type', 'scenario']
mask = df[lst_col_group].drop_duplicates().index
df_grouped = df.loc[mask]

group = df.groupby(lst_col_group, as_index=False)

df_grouped['val_rolmean'] = (
    group['val']
    .rolling(period_2*2, center=True, min_periods=1)
    .mean() * 12
    ).reset_index(drop=True)  # level=0 (it didn't work in this case)
df_grouped['val_rolmean2'] = (
    df_grouped['val_rolmean']/(
        df_grouped['rate'].shift(period).fillna(0) + 0.0050)
    ).reset_index(drop=True)  # level=0 (id didn't work in this case)
print(df_grouped.head())
#    id  type  scenario  val  rate  val_rolmean  val_rolmean2
# 0   3     3         3    3     1    20.000000   4000.000000
# 1   1     1         0    1     2    21.230769   4246.153846
# 2   1     3         1    0     1    19.714286   3942.857143
# 3   1     0         1    2     2    20.800000   4160.000000
# 4   2     2         3    3     0    19.500000   3900.000000
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem as I want to perform this operation groupwise, not on the entire dataset: `group['val_rolmean']/(group['rate'].shift(period).fillna(0) + 0.0050)`